# sizeThatFits doesn't work properly on iOS7 and works fine on iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, uitextview

```
CGSize size = [_textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(300, kTextViewHeight)];
```

It works different on ios7 and iOS8. In ios8 it gives me the height of the text properly, but in IOS7 it just leaves the height equal to kTextViewHeight. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

use `FLT_MAX` instead of `kTextViewHeight`:-

```
CGSize size = [_textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
```

Comment: I must have kTextViewHeight (= 160) so that my text doesnt go bigger than that. This is mandatory.